# how to get page id of a page using page slug

Tags: php, slug, id

I'm pretty new to WordPress and I was wondering if I could get a `page id` with its `slug`. Is it possible please let me know?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use `get_page_by_path($page_path)`:

```
$page = get_page_by_path( 'about' );
echo get_the_title( $page );
```

This will return a regular post object.
**Documentation:**
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_path/ 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/

Comment: What if it's a child page's id I want?

Comment: @freaky The function takes just the page slug, not the parent slug. Since slugs are unique, you will always get just one page.

Comment: Thank you it is working and for child page I had to navigate like hits `$page = get_page_by_path( 'about/child' );`

Comment: Just to clarify, `get_page_by_path` uses the `post_name` field internally, not `post_slug`.

Comment: Just to be clear, this uses the page path and not the page name, correct? Then a page named "About us" the argument should be "about-us", correct? with no beginning or trailing slashes?

Comment: Yes, @user658182

Answer (score 23):

I've been using this ..

```
function get_id_by_slug($page_slug) {
    $page = get_page_by_path($page_slug);
    if ($page) {
        return $page->ID;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: Why wrapping it in a function? `get_page_by_path` already returns null …

Comment: Because the OP question wants to return ID, not the page object.

Answer (score 11):

It has been already asked and answered on this forum. I am pasting the same code from there.
Use this function to retrieve page id.

```
 function get_page_by_slug($page_slug, $output = OBJECT, $post_type = 'page' ) { 
  global $wpdb; 
   $page = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND post_type= %s AND post_status = 'publish'", $page_slug, $post_type ) ); 
     if ( $page ) 
        return get_post($page, $output); 
    return null; 
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a function **url_to_postid** since WordPress v1.0.0 :) This task is easiest to achieve by using this function.

[url_to_postid](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/url_to_postid/)

When page is top-level page, only slug has to be given.

e.g. `url_to_postid('slug');`

When the page is in lower hierarchy level (i.e. it has parent) you have to prepend parent slug divided by slash like so:

```
url_to_postid('parent-slug/child-slug');
```

Edit: if this returns 0, you should flush permalinks (open the wordpress permalinks page in admin) - this is needed only once

Answer (score 3):

I had problems with the chosen answer when trying to use the code several times in the same page. It kept on displaying all of my pages content at the same time in every instance. So I went back to thinking and came up with this simpler approach based on the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)'s documentation:

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'pagename' => 'about-me' ) );
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<h2>'. get_the_title() .'</h2>';
        the_content();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Maybe it can still be helpful to somebody out there ;D

Answer (score 2):

A lot of answers here that seem overly complex, or don't describe how to get the page ID specifically.

```
            $page = get_page_by_path("your-page-slug");
            if ($page) {
                $page_id =  $page->ID;
                echo $page_id;
            }
```

In the above description we've assigned the post object to $page - Once you have the post object you can get any of the info described here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post

```
            $page->ID
            $page->post_status
            $page->post_title
```

and a lot more

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  function get_page_ID_by_slug( $slug ) {
    $page = get_page_by_path( $slug );
    if ( $page ) {
        return (int) $page->ID;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
?>
```

I hope this suggestion is helpful for someone.