# How to display page ids as page slug names?

Tags: customization, pages, slug, id

REF: [how to get page id of a page using page slug](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102841/how-to-get-page-id-of-a-page-using-page-slug)

I checked out the above answers but when I pasted any of the code into my child theme's function php file it didn't change anything. Here is the code I used:

```
<?php
// For this theme only - not the standard way of enqueing styles as per here: 
// https://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-child-theme?replies=3

function smallblog_child_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'smallblog-child', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'smallblog_child_scripts', 20 );

function get_id_by_slug($page_slug) {
    $page = get_page_by_path($page_slug);
    if ($page) {
        return $page->ID;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
} 
?>
```

The page id's are still only being displayed.

For example instead of it displaying

```
class="page page-id-53 page-template-default
```

I would like it to display:

```
class="page contact page-template-default //indicating that's the contact page
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the hook you're looking for is [`body_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/body_class/) or [`post_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_class/) filter. These filter will allow you to remove or push classes into an array which will in turn display them on the `body` tag or post tag respectively. To add the post slug we could do something like this:

```
/** 
 * Add, Remove, and Modify body classes
 * @note http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/236106/7355
 *
 * @param Array $classes
 *
 * @return Array $classes
 */
function theme_body_classes( $classes ) {
    global $post;

    if( is_object( $post ) ) {
        $classes[] = $post->post_name;
        $classes[] = "{$post->post_type}-{$post->post_name}";
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'theme_body_classes' );
```

Comment: Hi Howdy, thanks I tried this as well: http://bionicgirlnyc.com/testing but when inspecting the contact page for example in web dev tools it's still displaying the id. ?

Comment: @user2163224 I'm not sure I understand the issue then. When I view the Contact Page( using the link above ) and use Dev Tools to inspect the `body` tag it displays `contact page-contact` which sounds like what you're trying to do.